# How to integrate pages from third party website with custom style?

Tags: css

One of my clients pages like search page and contact page are hosted on third party website, which doesn't allow to add custom styling on the page,very limited option.
Is there any way to integrate the pages with the website so that its style can be best matched with other pages style ?
I tried to use iframe but this doesn't solve the purpose.

Comment: Does it allow to add scripts? If not, what exactly does it allow?

Answer (score 1):

The [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) doesn't allow you to make changes to a third party website. If they don't allow the insertion of styles or scripts directly on their page, then you are out of luck. You'll need to check with them if they offer other ways to access the page content (API).